# Choose which part of code will be executed, depending on the user's choice

Tags: java, html, servlets

I am currently developing a Java Web Dynamic Project and I have a Menu bar in my html page. When a user clicks one of the available options appearing on the menu, I want to be able to control which part of the code, in the matching Servlet, will be executed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your menu item is associated with a link, similar to this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>simple Servlet</title>
</head>
<body>
<ul>
    <li><a href="action?action=doThat">that Action</a></li>
    <li><a href="action?action=doThis">this Action</a></li>
</ul>

</body>
</html>
```

The deployment descriptor:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
          http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
         version="3.0">

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>action</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>de.so.ActionServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>action</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/action</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

And the servlet code:

```java
package de.so;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.Writer;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.*;

public class ActionServlet extends HttpServlet
{

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,
                         HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException,
            IOException
    {
        String action = request.getParameter("action");
        Writer out=response.getWriter();

        if (action == null || action.isEmpty())
        {
            out.write("Action empty");
        }
        else if (action.equals("doThis"))
        {
            out.write("perform this Action");
        }
        else if (action.equals("doThat"))
        {
            out.write("perform that Action");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @Draken Thanks for your answer. Your way works great! But I tried finding how    action?action=doThat really works and speciffically the use of question mark operator. I have used the ? operator in the past, but as a replacement for the if-else statement. Thanks again!!

Comment: You're welcome :-) but I'm not Draken :-)  `?` is not a operator, but simply a separator which departs the URI from the query string

Comment: Sorry for my mistake. I first saw Draken's name and being in a rush, I accidentally wrote his name. Oh, I see. Thank you very much, again!!!